# XOR Neural Network - unexpected results

Tags: swift, neural-network

I am trying to implement Daniel Shiffman's XOR Neural Network in swift, I have all the parts, but after training, the results are unexpected.

Part of me thinks it's the actual training system trying to learn multiple things at once.

[image: Results Screenshot]

I have linked my playground in case anyone can spot anything wrong: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rv8ku3d62h03ip/Neural.playground.zip?dl=0

Daniels code:

https://github.com/shiffman/The-Nature-of-Code-Examples/blob/master/chp10_nn/xor/code/src/Network.java

Comment: How many hidden layer nodes are you creating the network with? I've found that XOR with 1 hidden layer works much better when you have at least 3 nodes

Comment: I have 1 hidden layer, with 4 nodes

Comment: When initializing `Connection`, you give the `weight` property a random value in the range `[0, 1]`, but the weights should be randomized in the range `[-1, 1]`. Try to change the line `self.weight = we` in the initialization of `Connection` to `self.weight = 2*we-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code. The first (and most important) is a subtlety in the way you're creating your networks.

Right now you're using

```
inputs = [Neuron](repeating: Neuron(), count:2+1)
hidden = [Neuron](repeating: Neuron(), count:4+1)
```

But this creates all the inputs with the same `Neuron` and also all the `hidden` with the same `Neuron`, so there are only 4 `Neuron`s: 2 for input (the regular repeated 2 times and a bias neuron) and 2 for hidden (the regular repeated 4 times and 1 for bias).

You can solve it by simply using a for loop:

```
public class Network
{
    var inputs:[Neuron] = []
    var hidden:[Neuron] = []
    var output:Neuron!

    public init()
    {
        for _ in 1...2 {
            inputs.append(Neuron())
        }

        for _ in 1...4 {
            hidden.append(Neuron())
        }

        //print("inputs length: \(inputs.count)")

        inputs.append(Neuron(bias: true))
        hidden.append(Neuron(bias: true))

        output = Neuron()

        setupInputHidden()
        setupHiddenOutput()
    }

    ...
}
```

The other (minor) thing is when you calculate the output of a `Neuron` you're adding the bias instead of replacing it [(`bias = from.output*c.weight`)](https://github.com/shiffman/The-Nature-of-Code-Examples/blob/master/chp10_nn/xor/code/src/Neuron.java#L52), I don't know if that was on purpose but the result seems to be unaffected.

[image: Trained network]

Comment: ah! I had no idea "repeating:" uses the same first argument :-/ Thank you so much for clarifying and solving my problem. I'll award the points when stackoverflow lets me.